# Show that f is not surjective.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, where $S^1$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

(a) Show that there is a point $z \in S^1$ such that $f(z) = f(−z)$ where $z = (x, y), −z = (−x, −y)$

(b) Show that $f$ is not surjective.